# Want to run a binary having flags and arguments by using Go program

Tags: go

I want to run a binary file with flags.
If i directly run the binary it will be like following inside a golang program.

`./test --flag1 arg1 --flag2 arg2`

I was trying to run by the use of `os.exec`.

code:  `reslt ,err:= exec.Command("./test","--flag1", "arg1", "--flag2", "arg2").Output`

It is giving error:

> Exit status 2

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What's the content of `err` of your `exec.Command` call?

Comment: You'll still need to add the '--' to your flag arguments.

Comment: @Gerben yes , I missed that, edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output, err := exec.Command("./test","flag1", "arg1", "flag2", "arg2").Output()`

[Output](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) returns both a slice of bytes and an error. As indicated by the error, you are only expecting a single return value, whereas `Output` returns two.

EDIT: As for debugging your second problem, get the `stderr` from the command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("./test","flag1", "arg1", "flag2", "arg2")
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stderr = &stderr  
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(stderr.String())
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still I am getting a error, exit status 2

Answer (score 0):

I guess  Exit code 2 means 'no such a file or directory'. You should check path where you executed go binary and where test is.

Please try to specify absolute path for your cimmand first.

Comment: No,  I have tried  a different binary with no flags, that is working without absolute path.. this flags making the problem